# One-dimensional complex subspace of $\mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, vector-spaces

Let $A\in\text{GL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ be an invertible matrix of dimension $2$ with real coefficients. Consider the map $\iota:\mathbb{R}^4\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}^2$ given by $\iota(x,y,u,v)=(x+iy,u+iv)$. Define the set $V:=\left\{\left(x,y,(x,y)A^T\right)|\, x,y\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$. I would like to give a characterisation of all the matrices $A\in\text{GL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ such that the image $\iota(V)$ is a complex one-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{C}^2$. I have already tried to solve it by hand, writing out the definition of $\iota(V)$ and trying to deduce constraints for $A$ from the condition of being closed under linear combinations. However, the calculations are tedious. Does someone know a (more elegant) way of characterising the corresponding matrices and could help me out? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing out the definitions; let $A=\big(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\big)$ so that
$$\iota(V)=\{(x+yi,(ax+cy)+(bx+dy)i:\ x,y\in\Bbb{R}\}\subset\Bbb{C}^2.$$
This is a (necessarily one-dimensional) linear subspace of $\Bbb{C}^2$ if and only if
$$r(x+yi)+s( (ax+cy)+(bx+dy)i)=0,$$
for all $x,y\in\Bbb{R}$, for some $r,s\in\Bbb{C}$, not both zero. The above is equivalent to
$$\big((r+sa)+sbi\big)x+\big(sc+(r+sd)i\big)y=0,$$
which in particular implies that
$$r+sa+sbi=0\qquad\text{ and }\qquad sc+(r+sd)i=0.$$
It follows that
$$r=-s(a+bi)\qquad\text{ and }\qquad ri=-s(c+di),$$
and hence that $a=d$ and $b=-c$, so $A=\big(\begin{smallmatrix}\hphantom{-}a&b\\-b&a\end{smallmatrix}\big)$. This also shows that conversely, if $A=\big(\begin{smallmatrix}\hphantom{-}a&b\\-b&a\end{smallmatrix}\big)$, then
$$\iota(V)=\{(u,v)\in\Bbb{C}^2:\ (a+bi)u=v\}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, this helps me a lot! Could you just explain the step that there exits $r$ and $s$
(not both zero) for which the linear combination gives $0$ for all $x$ and $y$ ? And why is the dimension necessarily one then ?

Comment: If $\iota(V)$ is a $1$-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb{C}^2$ then it is defined by a linear equation; the coefficients are $r$ and $s$.

Comment: Note that $\iota(V)$ can only be $1$-dimensional because it is parametrized by $\Bbb{C}$ by
$$\iota(V)=\{\big(z,(a\operatorname{Re}(z)+c\operatorname{Im}(z))+(b\operatorname{Re}(z)+d\operatorname{Im}(z))i\big):\ z\in\Bbb{C}\}.$$
Alternatively, it is quite immediate from the definition that $\iota(V)\neq0$ and that $\iota(V)\neq\Bbb{C}^2$, so $\iota(V)$ can only be $1$-dimensional.